# Problems with a join not being lazy ;)

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my model I have a Batch that has many Dataset(s), each Dataset has many File(s) and a File hasMany sourceFiles.
We I retrieve the datasets also the sourceFiles are retrieved with
a long list of selects, even I am not requesting sourceFiles, or at least this is what I think.

This is my simplified model, I removed all non interesting stuff.

```
class Batch {
    static hasMany = [ datasets : Dataset]
}

class Dataset {
    File mainFile
    Batch batch

    static hasMany = [files : File]
    static mapping = {
        files column:"dataset_id"
    files joinTable:[name:"${Constants.phase3DB}${Constants.schemaName}.datasets_files"]
    files fetch:'join'
    }
}


class File {
    static hasMany = [ sourceFiles: String ] 
    static mapping = {
    sourceFiles joinTable: [name:
    "${Constants.phase3DB}${Constants.schemaName}.provenance",
    key:'product_file', column:'source_file', type:'text']
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my service:

```
Batch batch = Batch.get(batchId)
def datasets = Dataset.withCriteria {
    eq "batch", batch
    fetchMode "files", org.hibernate.FetchMode.JOIN
}
batch.datasets = datasets
```

Doing so I can see a select with a join to File:

```
select this_.dataset_id as dataset_1_14_1_, this_.active as active2_14_1_, this_.batch_id as batch_id3_14_1_, this_.deprecation_date as deprecat4_14_1_, this_.group_id as group_id5_14_1_, this_.version as version6_14_1_, this_.main_file_id as main_fil7_14_1_, files2_.dataset_id as dataset_1_14_3_, file3_.file_id as file_id2_15_3_, file3_.file_id as file_id1_18_0_, file3_.archive_id as archive_2_18_0_, file3_.archived as archived3_18_0_, file3_.catalog_extracted as catalog_4_18_0_, file3_.category as category5_18_0_, file3_.checksum as checksum6_18_0_, file3_.keywords_extracted as keywords7_18_0_, file3_.name as name8_18_0_, file3_.processing_date as processi9_18_0_, file3_.size as size10_18_0_
from phase3v2.dbo.datasets this_
left outer join phase3v2.dbo.datasets_files files2_ on this_.dataset_id=files2_.dataset_id
left outer join phase3v2.dbo.files file3_ on files2_.file_id=file3_.file_id
where this_.batch_id=?;
```

But immediately after I see a long list of queries like this:

```
select sourcefile0_.product_file as product_1_18_0_,
sourcefile0_.source_file as source_f2_20_0_ from phase3v2.dbo.provenance
sourcefile0_ where sourcefile0_.product_file=?
```

As I said I don't need the sourceFiles, but fine, let's retrieve them with a single query:

```
Batch batch = Batch.get(batchId)
def datasets = Dataset.withCriteria {
    eq "batch", batch
    fetchMode "files", org.hibernate.FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode "files.sourceFiles", org.hibernate.FetchMode.JOIN
}
batch.datasets = datasets
```

Doing so I have a null pointer exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

at
org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getLoadedCollectionOwnerOrNull(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:752)

at
org.hibernate.event.spi.AbstractCollectionEvent.getLoadedOwnerOrNull(AbstractCollectionEvent.java:75)

at
org.hibernate.event.spi.InitializeCollectionEvent.<init>(InitializeCollectionEvent.java:36)

at
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1895)

at
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)

at
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)

at
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)

at
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)

at
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:447)

at org.eso.phase3.rm.File.hashCode(File.groovy)

at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)

at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)

at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)

at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)

at
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:344)

at
org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:251)

at
org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:238)

at
org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:211)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.endCollectionLoad(Loader.java:1156)

at
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1125)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)

at
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)

at
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)

at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)

at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)

at
org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_withCriteria_closure11.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:305)

at
org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.doInSession(Unknown Source)

at
org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)

at
org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)

at
org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withCriteria(GormStaticApi.groovy:304)

at org.eso.phase3.rm.Dataset.withCriteria(Dataset.groovy)

at org.eso.phase3.rm.Dataset$withCriteria.call(Unknown Source)

at ConsoleScript0.run(ConsoleScript0:4)

at
org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
```

I really don't know what is going on. Any idea?

Comment: `files fetch:'join'` in domain class and `fetchMode "files", org.hibernate.FetchMode.JOIN` in criteria will always result an eager fetch of associated results. You would need `fetch: 'SELECT'` in domain class (which is the default behavior if nothing is specified) and `fetchMode` as SELECT as well if you want to join lazy. Refer docs for [fetch](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/fetch.html) and [fetchMode](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html)

Comment: I did that before, no change, but I think I found the problem. 
I will add an answer to this post and will open a ticket on github.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I can't add a comment to the original question yet....
Take a look at this wiki. I'm doing a many-to-many relationship right now and learned about it just now.

https://grails.org/wiki/Many-to-Many%20Mapping%20without%20Hibernate%20XML

Lazy Initialization Errors

You may encounter Hibernate Lazy Initialization errors when using this technique, especially if you attempt to access your domain collections from inside GSP templates (via the render template command in GSP pages). There is a work-around.

First, use the grails command to install the grails templates into your project:

```
grails install-templates
```

Next, locate the web.xml template, grails-app/src/templates/war/web.xml.

Add the following:

```
<!-- Hibernate -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.GrailsOpenSessionInViewFilter


</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- ~ Hibernate -->
```

Insert the above JUST BEFORE the first  in the template (it should be the charEncodingFilter).
It

Answer (score 0):

It came out that the problem was caused by an annotation introduced for testing purpouses. The domain class File had this on top: 
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode

If I remove @EqualsAndHashCode the sourceFiles selects disappear and if I add
fetchMode "files.sourceFiles", org.hibernate.FetchMode.JOIN
to the critera I don't have the null pointer exception anymore.

To me this looks like a bug or at least something that has to be very well documented.